# Linq to XML Querying Data in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Salary>40000</Salary>
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>7A Cox Street</Street>
      <City>Acampo</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Name>Lucy</Name>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Salary>20000</Salary>
    <Phone Type="Home">143-555-0763</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">434-555-0567</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>Jess Bay</Street>
      <City>Alta</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>95701</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
```

LINQ expression c#

```
var Pro = from u in doc.Descendants("Employee") select u;
        foreach (var x in Pro)
        {
            Response.Write(string.Format("EMP ID: {0}, Emp Name: {1}", x.Element("EmpId"), x.Element("Name")));
        }
```

I'm able to query the fields like EmpID, Name, Salary, etc.

**But How to query the Address fields like Street, City, State, Zip, Country?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to query all addresses, a specific address? Please be more explicit as for your need.

Comment: I would suggest you deserialize to your objects. It would be nicer and easier.

Comment: How to deserialize objects in XML? sorry to be DUMB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
x.Descendants("Address").First().Element("Street")
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Why we have to use First()?

Comment: Because you could have several addresses per Employee. First() takes the first one

Answer (score 1):

I would also do what Reniuz suggested and deserialize to an object but here is an example of how you currently do it:

```
foreach (var x in Pro)
        {
            Response.Write("EMP ID: {0}, Emp Name: {1}\r\n", x.Element("EmpId"), x.Element("Name"));
            var adrs = x.Descendants("Address");
            foreach (var a in adrs)
            {
                Response.Write("\tAddress Street: {0}, City: {1}\r\n", a.Element("Street"), a.Element("City"));    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take XML into the Variable and Use Like

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XMLVariableString);    

var FirstPart = from node in doc.Descendants("items") select node; //Select Data from doc using 

List<ListName> valuesNodes = new List<ListName>(); //create any with i.e <==
```

Create One `List` with the Same Name as in `XML` and Created `Sub List` for `Address` Containing the all the fields of `Address`

Use the Same Query you have used but select from `FirstPart`.

Now you can easily handle data from `var FirstPart`

Answer (score 0):

The Address elements you are trying to look for can be accessed by first selecting all the Address elements by using `x.Elements("Address")`.  Each nested Address element can then be selected using the `.Element()` function.

So the parameters for `Response.Write()` should look something like:

```
x.Elements("Address").Element("Street");
```

Comment: Element() Method is not recognized. Its only recognized when: x.Descendants("Address").First().Element("Street"). Why?